# Why do we need "Relationships" between tables at all?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Say we have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tblProduct
(`Product_ID` int, `Product_Name` varchar(7));
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE tblProductExtended
(`Product_ID` int, `Product_Size` int, `Product_Quantity` int);
```

With these values:

```
INSERT INTO tblProduct
    (`Product_ID`, `Product_Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Shoes1'),
    (2, 'Shoes2');
```

And

```
INSERT INTO tblProductExtended
    (`Product_ID`, `Product_size`, `Product_Quantity`)
VALUES
    (1, 36, 20),
    (1, 37, 20),
    (1, 38, 30),
    (2, 36, 50),
    (2, 37, 60),
    (2, 37, 75);
```

Now obviously, the Product_ID in the tblProductExpanded should be the FK of Product_ID of tblProduct. However, I can still query:

```
SELECT tblProduct.Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Size, Product_Quantity
FROM tblProduct
INNER JOIN tblProductExtended ON tblProduct.Product_id = tblProductExtended.Product_id
```

Which returns:

```
Product_ID  Product_Name    Product_Size    Product_Quantity
1   Shoes1  36  20
1   Shoes1  37  20
1   Shoes1  38  30
2   Shoes2  36  50
2   Shoes2  37  60
2   Shoes2  37  75
```

So can someone please explain to me, why do we need "Relationships" at all if we can Query the same info regardless of relationship (AFAIK)? What is the actual use of them, apart from having to spend time setting them up.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I mean users themselves don't have access to the databse itself, only the forms (assuming we talk about MS Access) and we can specify what shows up where in the form as if it were in the relationship (e.g. combobox of Product_ID in the Product_ID field in the form shows up, and so user is forced to pick 1 and not input a random number).

Comment: In addition to Referential Integrity enforcement, two other advantages of setting up Relationships in Access are (1) it documents the relationship between the tables so if you run Database Documenter it will show up there, and (2) if you are creating queries in the Query Designer it can automatically establish the joins between the tables (and do it without "guessing").

Comment: Sorry @HansUp I will delete the mysql tag. I'm talking purely about MS-Access, but to visualise the situation better I used SQL itself.

Comment: @Gord Thompson (1) is a valid point for big databases, I can see that, but is it really needed for small ones where we have few tables only?, (2) well assuming I build my queries using SQL code alone (and not query design), that is irrelevant (I believe).

Comment: Forgive me, but it sounds like you are just asking for an excuse to be lazy.

Comment: Well isn't software in general a tool to make a task quickly and effectively? Which in turn could be observed as "lazy people don't want to spend 10 hours sitting in front of PC doing same thing over and over again". Hence I was asking the point of it - if it wasn't needed, it wouldn't be invented, and I couldn't quite figure out why it is needed in the first place if everything can be done without it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the main reason is for data integrity. If you have a relationship between two tables `invoice and invoice_item`. You won't be able to add an invoice item that does not related to an invoice. This is what you want!

It's called [referential integrity](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-referential-integrity/). It can get pretty messy in your database if you don't have foreign keys because you could delete and corrupt your data easily.

e.g. You could delete invoice and not it's corresponding invoice items. This is considered bad.

I think this gives you something to go on.

Comment: I get that part, but cannot this be handled in the interface user works with already? I mean in the code behind the interface, so if he wanted to delete a specific invoice, a warning message pops up and warns you that with this action you also would delete corresponding invoice items, then user selects yes/no/whatever options the business wants and the code behind the interface handles the deletion of corresponding items if user presses "yes".

Comment: Yes it can, but that should be your first line of defence. You should always try maintain the integrity of your data at the source - your database. What if someone logs onto your database and deletes data through that. This is very common, bug fixes, fixing data, etc. You should write defensive code.

Comment: As @Ryan-NealMes states, it is a good idea to protect your data integrity at all levels, much in the way that we are concerned with security.    Multiple levels helps provide backup if one area fails.  Starting with the database (which where your data, after all, lives) is a logical first step

Comment: I know this is old, but I'd add my 2 cents: relationships also help in automate (read: reduce) the code behind your interface, e.g. you can set your FK to deny deletion of master record if details exists, so when a user tries to delete an invoice with related items, the RDBMS prohibites this, returns an error and your code should only react to this error, simpler than checking items existence by yourself. On the contrary, if you want items to be automatically deleted if invoice is being deleted, set your FK to cascade the deletion to details and you'll get the job done for free ;)

Answer (score 3):

A relationship between tables is an important aspect of a good relational database.

1) It establishes a connection between a pair of tables that are logically related to each other.

2) It helps to refine table structures and minimize redundant data.

3) It is the mechanism that enables you to fetch data from multiple tables simultaneously.

4) Relationships are a necessary also to maintain your database in normalization form which is a part of relational Database Rule.

5) And also as @Ryan-Neal Mes said in answer above:- to maintain referential integrity which is a subpart of relationship concept.

A well-defined relationship ensures relationship-level integrity in Database, which guarantees that the relationship itself is reliable.You can take advantage of the many benefits a relational database provides only when you establish each relationship carefully and properly.

Failure to do so(not well-defined relationship in DB) means that you will have a tough time with data from multiple tables, and certainly facing problems when you try to insert, update, or delete records in related tables.